# Ansible retrieve multiple array values from module output

Tags: loops, ansible

Consider the following returned data from an ansible module, I register the results in a variable called kibana_lc_all.

I'd like to be able to iterate over all of the name values, but I'm not sure how to do so with Ansible...  I know I can print the first value via:

```
- debug:
    msg: "LC info is: {{ kibana_lc_all.results[0].name }}"
```

But how could I iterate and either print all 3 names, or store the 3 names in an array variable and iterate over them later in another task?  Also, there won't always be 3 names, could be anywhere from 1 to 20...

```
  {
   u'results':[  
   {  
      u'ram_disk_id':u'',
      u'name':u'pro-ELK-Kibana-20170628-1152',
      u'image_id':u'ami-1a96a60c'
   },
   {
      u'ram_disk_id':u'',
      u'name':u'pro-ELK-Kibana-20170625-1050',
      u'image_id':u'ami-1b97d64f'
   }, 
   {
      u'ram_disk_id':u'',
      u'name':u'pro-ELK-Kibana-20170621-0931',
      u'image_id':u'ami-1b97d64f'
   },
  ]
 }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [map](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/2.9/templates/#map) filter:

```
- set_fact:
    my_list: "{{ kibana_lc_all.results | map(attribute='name') | list }}"
```

or [json_query](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_filters.html#json-query-filter) filter:

```
- set_fact:
    my_list: "{{ kibana_lc_all | json_query('results[].name') }}"
```

Comment: Thank you, I was close as I had stumbled on the json_query, but wasn't quite sure of the syntax.   One more follow up question.  Now that I have a list, is there any easy way to cut X elements off the array?  i.e. I want to do actions against all list values except the first two items.

Comment: Ah, I think I found it, reading up on jmsepath, I can use the json_query to just grab from array element 2 on, via lc_list: "{{ kibana_lc_all | json_query('results[2:].name') }}"